Is feature-extraction and dimensionality-reduction a kind of compression?
I'm struggling to understand what these terms have in common:

Feature extraction
Feature selection
Compression
Dimensionality reduction

Relatedly, the information / entropy in our data should always stay the same, so what are we actually adding / reducing?

Sort of, but not really.
Taken from [1]

"While dimensionality reduction can be seen as a simplistic form of
compression, it is not equivalent to it, as the goal of compression is
to reduce the entropy of the representation under a prior probability
model shared between the sender and the receiver (the entropy model),
not only the dimensionality."

In fact, you don't even need dimensionality reduction to achieve compression. A popular paradigm for lossy compression is to implement or train a parametric transform that gaussianizes your sample and reduce the entropy of your latent [2][3]. Assuming an adequate entropy model, regardless of how large your latent is, a stream entropy coder will produce a bitstring that is close to the entropy of your latent. Dimensionality reduction can still be useful for compression. However, I'd argue, that dimensionality reduction's main benefit is to increase computational efficiency, in particular for the entropy coder.

Dimensionality reduction can do quite good compression. Imagine you have a bunch of grayscale images, each has width and height equal to n. They can be represented by a big n * n vector, with values ranging from 0 = black to 255 = white. Say you have m images, you would need m * n * n numbers from 0 to 255 (8 bits) to store them all. Now realize that as we are representing the images as vectors, we can try to perform some sort of dimensionality reduction on all of them, say with PCA. If the images are similar, we will be able to reduce by a really large margin the number of elements needed to represent it, and even if the images are not similar, it would still work pretty well. Say we can now represent an image with k elements, instead of n * n, but with k << n * n. This would mean we would need to store k images with their regular size (n * n), and the compression would be a linear combination of the k images we have stored, so we would store k * n * n pixels instead of m * n * n, with k << m, and would need to store k values for each image, giving k * n * n + m * k total values, wich should be way less than the original m * n * n. Note that if we didn't have so many images (small m), than we could aply PCA to each row of each image, because the number of rows will probably be large, still resulting in a good compression. This is just one way you can do it with PCA, but the idea is generally something similar to that.
Feature extraction and selection is what dimensionality reduction methods do. Feature selection is simply choosing what variables that you already have you will use, basically picking what is valiable information to the model to learn what you want. While doing this, you will likely discart information that has nothing to do with what you are trying to analyse, for example, if you have a dataset with a few characteristics about a person, and how ofter it gets sick. Features you would probably take into consideration are things like his weight, if he exercises frequently, his age etc. but you probably don't need to know the person's name or other unrelated things, so you would only extract related features. This in itself would be a form of dimensionality reduction, as you would throw away some features
Feature extraction is a little more interesting. It creates new features, based on the original, basically trying to make new features that can best represent the originals, but in the smallest number of features possible. This is what PCA does, and can be best understood by visualizing it I think:

in the image, the original features are represented by the x and y axis, than there are PCs 1 and 2 (the two principal components). The PCs are the newly created features, and you can see that if you would represent your data with only a single feature, it should be the PC 1 (probably, it really depends on the dataset), because it maintains the most variance, while with PC 2 you would loose much more variance. By saying you would represent you data with only PC 1, you should think of projecting all the points onto the PC 1 line, and you can see that by projecting it into the PC 1 line, you have a much greater range of values than projecting on PC 2, probably meaning you should use only PC 1 if you were to only use 1 feature
I'm sorry if this is too long and if I was confusing along the way, I'm free to answer any questions about it

This was an amazing read and really cleared everything up for me. Thank you so much for taking your time @Osmar - this was really helpful.

You could upvote this post if you found it helpful then. :)

I don't have enough points to upvote but i marked this answer to have resolved my question.
One small follow up question: Can dimensionality-reduction be really called compression? Because when we're using an autoencoder we have some errors in the reconstruction (= loss of information)?

For an illustration see What is the intuition behind SVD?

@sueszli I'm not shure I understand you question but compression does not have to be lossless. If you use PCA to compress a bunch of images it will often loose some quality, unless some of the last principal components have length 0 (wich mean they don't affect the final result). In that case, you can safelly discart the length 0 PCs, and maintain lossless compression, but still most cases will lose some quality, what it's really trying to do is loose as little as possible.

@Osmar Thank you so much - I forgot compression is allowed to be lossy. This clears everything up!

I agree with the other answer that dimensionality reduction is a form of compression (perhaps lossy compression). However, I contest the notion that feature extraction must be a form of compression.
Imagine the fairly common situation of measuring two variables that you believe are predictive of an outcome. You also think their interaction matters, that the impact one variables has on the outcome of interest depends on the value of the other variable. Thus, your feature extraction also includes the product of the original two features. Now, instead of having a feature space of $x_1$ and $x_2$, you have a feature space of $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3=x_1x_2$. This is not compression. If anything, this is expansion, with the information required to represent the new feature space either being the three variables explicitly or the original two variables in addition to the way they are combined to give the third variable.
